# Find area bounded by parabola $y^2=2px,p\in\mathbb R$ and normal to parabola that closes an angle $\alpha=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ with the positive $Ox$ axis.

Tags: calculus, integration, analytic-geometry, area

Let $p=-2<0\Rightarrow y=\sqrt{-4x} \lor y=-\sqrt{-4x}\Rightarrow x\le 0 $.

Let $p=2>0\Rightarrow y=\sqrt{4x} \lor y=-\sqrt{4x}\Rightarrow x\ge 0 $.

For $p>0$ we can find the equation for normal to parabola such that it closes  an angle $\alpha=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ with the positive $Ox$ axis, but for $p<0$ we can't find the normal.

**Question**: Is it correct that for $p<0$ we can't find normal to the given parabola?

How to find the equation of normal if the angle is given?

**EDIT**:

I am getting the negative result for total area. Here is how I integrated:

$A=A_1-A_2$ where $A_1$ is the area below $y^2=2px,p>0$ on interval $[-3p,p]$ integrating on $y$ axis.
$A_2$ is the area below $y=-x+\frac{3p}{2},p>0$ on interval $[-3p,p]$integrating on $y$ axis.

$A=\int\limits_{-3p}^p \left(\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{3p-2y}{2}\right)\mathrm dy$

$A_1=\int\limits_{-3p}^{p} \frac{y^2}{2}\mathrm dy=\frac{14p^3}{3},p>0$

$A_2=\int\limits_{-3p}^{p}\frac{3p-2y}{2} \mathrm dy=10p^2$

$A=A_1-A_2=\frac{2p^2(7p-15)}{2}$

Why is this wrong? It should be positive for every $p>0$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The situation for $p>0$ or $p<0$ is symmetric with respect to the origin. ( see the figure)
[image]

The point $A$ is the point where the tangent to the parabola  forms an angle of $\pi/4$ with the $x-$axis, so you can find it solving $y'(x)=1$ for $y=\sqrt{2px}$ ( and find $A=(\frac{p}{2},p)$).

The line $AB$ has slope $m=-1$ ad contains $A$

can you do from this?

Finally: note that if you want the area of the region between the line and the parabola it is simpler to change axis with a transformation: $(x,y) \rightarrow (y,x)$.

Comment: How do you find point $A$ such that the normal on parabola  closes an angle $\alpha=3\pi/4$ with positive $x$ axis?

Comment: The line $AB$ is orthogonal to the tangent in $A$ and forms an angle $3\pi/2$ with the positive $x-$ axis, so the tangent at this point forma an angle of $\pi/4$ and has slope $m=1$. This means that $A$ is the point of $y=\sqrt{2px}$ such that $y'=1$. Take the derivative and solve the equation.

Comment: How to find coordinates for point $B$?

Comment: have you found the equation of the line $AB$? Now solve the system of this e equation and the equation of the parabola and you find the two common points.

Comment: I have found the equation for $AB$ using coordinates of $A$ : $y=-x+\frac{3p}{2},p>0$. Solving the system $y=-x+\frac{3p}{2},y^2=2px\Rightarrow y^2+3py-3p^2=0\Rightarrow y_1=\frac{-3p-\sqrt{21}p}{2},y_2=\frac{-3p+\sqrt{21}p}{2}$. We get $B=(7.2,\frac{-3p-\sqrt{21}p}{2})$. How to integrate these two functions to get the area?

Comment: Correction: $B=\left(\frac{{y_1}^2}{2p},\frac{-3p-\sqrt{21}p}{2}\right),p>0$

Comment: Your solution fo $B$ is wrong. We have $B=(9p/2,-3p)$. For the area af the figure you have to divide the region in two parts, but, as I have suggested, it's simpler to do a symmentry that change $x$ and $y$ axis.

Answer (score 1):

Emilio Novati has already provided a good hint. This answer is to the following question in the **EDIT** :

> Why is this wrong?

Since $y^2=2px\Rightarrow x=\frac{y^2}{2p}$, you should have
$$A_1=\int_{-3p}^{p}\frac{y^2}{2\color{red}{p}}\mathrm dy=\frac{14}{3}p^{\color{red}{2}}$$

Then, note also that 
$$A=A_{\color{red}{2}}-A_{\color{red}{1}}=10p^2-\frac{14}{3}p^2=\frac{16}{3}p^2$$